# Why + + on strings gives strange result

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I was working on appending the element dynamically using jQuery and found that when using `+ +` it shows `NaN` and the next text is not added.

I can guess that somehow `+ +` works here as Arithmetic plus operator and returns `NaN`.

This is not Increment operator as there is space between the two `+`.

My Question is

1. What is actually happening here so it returns `NaN`
2. Why `+` here does not work as concatenation operator when it is surrounded by strings.

```js
$('#message').html('<span>' + + ' new message</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"></div>
```

The same behaviour can be seen in Node.js

```
> 'a' + + 'b' // aNaN
```

**Note:** I know that I've added an extra `+` here and removing that will work for me.

Comment: 'a' + + 'b' is like 'a' + NaN + 'b'

Comment: @Omidam81 that's not correct - see answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding +"" to string appends "0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894778/adding-to-string-appends-0)

Comment: @TylerH See the date when the question was asked before closing as dupe

Comment: @Tushar Question and answer quality and activity are more important than asking date for existing questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is because by placing the `+` character before a string you're attempting to convert the `'b'` string to a number, which results in `NaN`. The code in your question is equivalent to this:

```
'a' + Number('b')
```

Hence `Number('b')` returns `NaN` which is then coerced to a string and appended to `a`. This behaviour is intrinsic to JS, so the library being used (whether jQuery, node or any other) is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now

Comment: No problem glad to help.

Answer (score 8):

Because the second `+` is evaluated as a [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator like

```
'<span>' + + ' new message</span>'
= '<span>' + (+' new message</span>')
= '<span>' + NaN
= <span>NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

The javascript first try to convert string `'b'` to number and returns `NaN`because `'b'` can not convert to number. Then `'a' + 'NaN'` concatenate to new string `'aNaN'`. Same in your example:

```
$('#message').html('<span>' + + ' new message</span>');
```

Javascript tries to convert `+ ' new message</span>'` to a number and returns `NaN`. Then `'<span>' + 'NaN'` creates a new `span` element and `NaN` as text.

Take a look:

[Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
>   already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers,
>   unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something
>   into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the
>   number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats,
>   as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in
>   both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
>   Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
>   parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator can be used to convert a variable to a number.  So this...

```
"a" + + "b"
```

returns `aNaN`, but this...

```
"a" + + "5"
```

returns `a5`

Since `b` is not a number, `+ b` returns NaN.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try like this:

```
$('#message').html('<span>' + ' new message</span>');
```

**or**

```
 $('#message').html('<span>' + '' + ' new message</span>');
```

==========================================

```js
$('#message').html('<span>' + ' new message</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Like the previously deleted answer - this misses the point of the question