# Adding +"" to string appends "0"

Tags: javascript

By an accidental typo I've encountered a behavior which I cannot explain.

When I have

```
var text = "abc";
text += + "";
```

the `text` variable suddenly becomes `abc0`.

Can someone provide any insight on this, please?

Comment: Try typing `+ ""` in the console.

Comment: `var text = "abc" +(+ "");` does the same ;)

Comment: [Let's talk about Javascript...](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945493/why-on-strings-gives-strange-result

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`+ ""` evaluates to the number `0`. This is because in order to apply the unary plus operator, `""` is coerced to a number--the same as `Number("")`, which results in `0` if the string is empty or blank.

When you then "add" (`+` or in this case `+=`) the number `0` to the string `"abc"`, it is coerced to the string `"0"`, resulting in `"abc0"`.

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber):

> A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0.

Comment: *Just JavaScript things*. At least it's documented, but it's these little things that you don't expect (well you should because it's not a typed language), and then they crash your system.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: JavaScript is (dynamically) typed, the problem is all those strange coercions where you would rather have a syntax error or a runtime exception.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, dynamically typed; well to me that's close enough to *not typed at all*. I remember when I was throwing around `typeof` and `instanceof` to try to ensure types (at least of `Object`s that I was working with). I do **not** miss that, too much room for error! Especially when you expect something to happen and it takes you 5 hours to debug why it *didn't* because some runtime exception was thrown and you can't catch it efficiently. And working on *backend* systems in JS? I  like the idea of Node.js for example, but working with it really sucks in my experience.

Answer (score 10):

As you can see in TypeScript `(+ "")` is a number (0):

[image]

Comment: Typescript is such a lovely language. :)

Answer (score 1):

from: http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/

In JavaScript it is possible to use the + operator alone before a single element. This indicates a math operation and tries to convert the element to a number. If the conversion fails, it will evaluate to NaN. This is especially useful when one wants to convert a string to a number quickly, but can also be used on a select set of other types.